# Adding a column from One DataSet to other

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net, datatable

have a Dataset Ds1 and dataset Ds2 , DS1 has Product_ID, product information and ds2 has Product_ID, product_type.

for the matching product_id, I want to add the Product_tye column from ds2 to ds1 .

Note: Product_id is not primary key in ds 1, the result set has many products with same product_id. In ds 2, product_id is unique. also, those datatbles are from two different databases on different servers and has different credentials , so cant use sql joins.

I tried to use linq to acheive this, but not getting the desired output, please correct me if i am mising something .

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
//After both the datatble has values, using linq to add datatble columsn, 

DataTable result = (from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                            join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<string>("productID") equals t2.Field<string>("productID")
                            select t1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I dount this will go that simple. You have to create a new column in table1, then loop through rows of both tables and check for ids and add prodict_type to exact row of table1, based on product id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting both tables

```
DataTable result = (from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                        join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<string>("productID")  
                                     equals t2.Field<string>("productID")
                        select new {t1,t2}
                    ).CopyToDataTable();
```

OR Selecting selected columns

```
DataTable result = (from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                        join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<string>("productID") 
                                      equals t2.Field<string>("productID")
                        select new {
                         productId = t1.productID, 
                         col2 = t1.col2,...,
                         productType = t2.pruductType
                    ).CopyToDataTable();
```

NOTE: I think productID type should be `int` type so replace `string` with int in that case

Comment: Second query: need to close the curly bracket after selected column list. `select new {....}`

Answer (score 0):

I have just created you a simple example, what you have to do is to change column names from my code, with your own:

```
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        table1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        table2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        table2.Columns.Add("age", typeof(int));

        table1.Rows.Add(1, "mitja");
        table1.Rows.Add(2, "sandra");
        table1.Rows.Add(3, "nataška");

        table2.Rows.Add(1, 31);
        table2.Rows.Add(3, 24);
        table2.Rows.Add(4, 46);

        DataTable targetTable = table1.Clone();
        //create new column
        targetTable.Columns.Add("age");

        var results = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                      join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>("id") equals t2.Field<int>("id")
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = (int)t1["id"],
                          NAME = (string)t1["name"],
                          AGE = (int)t2["age"]
                      };

        foreach (var item in results)
            targetTable.Rows.Add(item.ID, item.NAME, item.AGE);
```

Be careful on defining type of variables (int, string, ...) in any case!!!
Hope it helps.